# approach for $\int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been wrestling with this one all afternoon and I don't get it. I just can't figure out a way to remove that blasted square root from there and I am getting really frustrated.

$$\int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x}}dx$$

I know the answer is $2\ln(\sqrt{x}+1)$, I don't care about that, I just want to know how to approach it. Parts does not work (you are left with a logarithm and the root), substitution with $t^2=x$ does not help(you are left with $\sqrt{t}$ anyway), this is not a rational one and playing with $\sqrt{x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}$ has not worked either.

I'm out of ideas, which is the correct path to this kind of integrals?

Comment: Let $u^2=x$, then let $u=\tan\theta$.

Comment: The derivative of $2\ln(\sqrt x+1)$ is $1/(x+\sqrt x)$, not $1/(x+1)\sqrt x$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Then the textbook may be wrong, I'll consult with the teacher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
u & = \sqrt{x} \\[10pt]
u^2 & = x \\[10pt]
2u\,du & = dx \\[10pt]
\end{align}
$$
\int \frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x}} dx = \int \frac{1}{(u^2+1)u}\, 2u\,du = \int \frac{2}{u^2+1} \, du
$$
etc.

This is called a rationalizing substitution.  "Rationalizing" means getting rid of the radical, i.e. the square root sign.

Comment: OK I see my mistake now, after substituting $t=\sqrt(x)$, I kept writing $x=\sqrt(t)$ for some reason. I need a nap or something, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put $y = \sqrt{x}, dy = \dfrac{dx}{2 \sqrt{x}}, y^2 = x$

Therefore, integral becomes
$$\int \dfrac{2}{(1+y^2)}dy = 2\arctan{y}+c = 2\arctan{\sqrt{x}}+c$$
Sorry for the clumsy writing, answered from phone.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=w^2$, then $dx=2w dw$ and
$$\int \frac{xdx}{(x+1)\sqrt{x}}=\int \frac{w^2 2w dw}{(w^2+1)w}=2\int \frac{w^2}{w^2+1}dw= $$
$$=2\int \frac{w^2+1-1}{w^2+1}dw= 2\int dw-2\int \frac{dw}{w^2+1} =$$
$$=2w-2\arctan w+c =2\sqrt{x}+\arctan \sqrt{x}+c. $$

Comment: The integrand is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}$ and not $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=w^2$, then $dx=2w dw$ and
$$\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{x}}=\int \frac{ 2w dw}{(w^2+1)w}=2\int \frac{1}{w^2+1}dw= $$

$$=2\arctan w+c =2\arctan \sqrt{x}+c. $$